# Why Jquery doesnt listen to event click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, click

I have an html with connected js file it's working.

When I try to  write `$('#userAdd').click(addUser);` in Google Console(Inspector).

My js .click looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userAdd').click(addUser());
});
```

Html element looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">                                    
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-12">
 <input id="userAdd" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn col-md-12 btn-primary ">
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I put some breakpoints in "Sources" of Inspector on my `.click` and it is only working when page is loaded or reloaded.

Update: now everything is working solution was

```
$('#userAdd').click(function() { addUser(); });
```

And this one is not working for some reason

```
$('#userAdd').click(addUser);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Remove the inner parenthesis in `click(addUser())`. It should be `click(addUser)`. The parenthesis after the function name calls it immediately.

Comment: @AndrewL. No, console is absolutely clear

Comment: And i'd change the input type to "button"

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
$('#userAdd').click(addUser());
                           ^^
```

Since you have `()`, the `addUser` function is IMMEDIATELY called, and its return value is what becomes the argument to `click()`. Try

```
    $('#userAdd').click(addUser);
or  $('#userAdd').click(function() { addUser(); });
```

instead.

Comment: @ Marc B .Wow, so  now  i  understand more why  my  debuger was so whild :DDD
Thanks.
Also helped solution of @I'm Back